# Android device monitor don't launch in Ubuntu

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

I'm trying to launch Android device monitor and i keep getting a window with these informations :

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /home/ak/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/ak/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/monitor
-name Monitor
--launcher.library /home/ak/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/ak/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 5c7f000d
-data @noDefault
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /home/ak/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

and when i tried launching it in emulator i got this error message :

```
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=256m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

PS : i've encountered the same problem with other programs , i got the same window of error ...Any help !

Comment: You're mentioning `MaxPermSize=256m` twice in the command, can you change it to be just once and see what happens?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Android Device Monitor requires another version of java. I had the same problem in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. In my OS there were java8 and java9. Java9 was current. Switching to java8 solved the problem. To select necessary version use command:
**sudo update-alternatives --config java**

Comment: You are my Hero!